# Realtime Supabase not working when I do a migration with Prisma

Tags: real-time, database-migration, prisma, supabase, supabase-database

i'm working on a project using nextjs, react, typescript, Supabase and Prisma. And I Plan to build a chat with Realtime.

The Realtime database work when I create it, but when I do a migration with Prisma (a migration that delete everything in the db) it break the realtime:

here's the log(event message):

```
Subscribing to PostgreSQL failed:
{:error, 
"Subscription insert failed with error: ERROR P0001 (raise_exception)
invalid column for filter chatId.

Check that tables are part of publication supabase_realtime and
subscription params are correct: %{
   \"event\" => \"*\", \"filter\" => \"chatId=eq.03a0c7c2-32b-35-aa35-9be54c798\",
   \"schema\" => \"public\", \"table\" => \"message\"
  }"
}
```

it says that it raises an exception from a postgreSQL ERROR P0001

It occurs when I migrate the database, any thought on how to fix that ? I'm using Prisma 5.1.1. if I remember, it did the same on older version (lasts versions of prisma 4).

I tried to update Prisma, to disable realtime before migration, change my realtime function parameter

Here's the realtime function:

```
        const filter = `chatId=eq.${myChatInfo?.id}`
        let allMessagesInCallBack = allMessages

            const messageChannel = supabase.channel("realtime for messages")
                .on(
                    'postgres_changes',
                    {
                        event: '*',
                        schema: 'public',
                        table: 'message',
                        filter: filter
                    },
                    (payload) => {
                        allMessagesInCallBack = updateMessagesInBlocks(allMessagesInCallBack, payload)
                        dispatch(setMessageList(allMessagesInCallBack));
                    }).subscribe();
            return () => { supabase.removeChannel(messageChannel) };
```

added tons of console.log, but I can't figure it out.

Edit 1: forgot to say that it's my third time restarting a new database project with Supabase, no problems at the beginning, only when a migration is done.

Edit 2: I just tried to recreate the bug with drizzleORM and it didn't break. What i've seen from drizzle is that they store their drizzle_migration table in another schema in Supabase. When they apply their migration, they didn't remove everything and insert all the tables migration per migration. I'll use drizzle for now.

If someone know the answer for this error, please answer it.

Comment: I would check if the tables under `realtime` schema are properly restored after the migration.

Comment: Everything is restored, every table, column. I restarted my project without any probrem but that one. I'll check if the error occurs with other methods like supabase, other ORMs